# Using NumPy Vectorization to Create Column Containing Length of Another Column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I think I have a pretty straightforward question here. Essentially I have a table with one column where each row contains a set of values that had previously been converted from a JSON string.

For example, here is one cell value for the column "options":

```
[u'Tide Liquid with a Touch of Downy April Fresh 69oz', u'Tide Liquid with Febreze Spring & Renewal 69oz (HE or Non-HE)', u'Tide Liquid HE with Febreze Sport 69oz', u'Tide Liquid HE Clean Breeze 75oz', u'Tide Liquid Original 75oz', u'Other']
```

I want to add a new column that simply counts the number of values in this list. I can do this row by row using a code like such:

```
df['num_choices'] = len(df.loc[row_num,'options'])
```

(i.e. I want to count the number of values in the column "options" and return that count in a new column called "num_choices")

Running this on the provided example above (with the input row#) will create a new column next to it with the value 6, since the count of options is 6.

How can I do this systematically for all 5,000 of my rows?

I tried to do this with Pandas iterrow() function, but I've been told that would be way less efficient than simply using NumPy ndArray vectorization. But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't think there is any way to vectorize it since that column just contains arbitrary Python objects rather than a homogeneous array

Comment: @ali_m they're not necessarily arbitrary though - the len() command works on that column individually and is able to count the number of objects, so why should it not be able to do it on a mass scale?

Comment: As far as numpy is concerned, a `list` counts as an arbitrary Python object. numpy can only efficiently deal with arrays that have regular dimensions and contain elements of a constant size in memory (this all has to do with numpy's [internal representation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) of the array). This doesn't apply to Python lists, since the length and item size can vary arbitrarily.

Comment: @ali_m got it thank you for the explanation! Do you know how I might be able to do this with Pandas iterrow?

Comment: I don't really see any reason to use `iterrow`. I would probably do something like `df['num_choices'] = np.array([len(row) for row in df.options])`

Comment: @ali_m That's actually just the answer I was originally looking for! Is there someway I can mark your comment to this as the correct answer? Or do you want to make it an answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, there's not really any way to vectorize operations on arrays that contain arbitrary Python objects.

I don't think you can do much better than using a simple `for` loop or list comprehension, e.g.:

```
df['num_choices'] = np.array([len(row) for row in df.options])
```